# Why TypeScript does not infer the type of values and how to avoid this behavior

Tags: typescript, type-inference, value-type

I implements type-safe router in TypeScript and have a trouble with inferring types.

```js
export interface Route<Args> {
  match(path: string): Args | void;
  build(args: Args): string;
}

export type Routes<State> = {[Tag in keyof State]: Route<State[Tag]>};

export interface Router<State> {
  match(path: string): Partial<State> | void;
  build(state: Partial<State>): string;
}

export function createRouter<State>(routes: Routes<State>): Router<State> {
  /* ... */ return {} as any;
}

const root: Route<{}> = {
  match: (path) => /* ... */ undefined,
  build: () => '/'
};

const blog: Route<{ id: string }> = {
  match: (path) => /* ... */ undefined,
  build: ({ id }) => '/blog/' + id
};

const router1 = createRouter({ root, blog });
const router2 = createRouter<{ root: {}, blog: { id: string } }>({ root, blog });
const router3 = createRouter(<Routes<{ root: {}, blog: { id: string } }>>{ root, blog });
```

The inferred type of `router1` is a `Router<{root: any, blog: any}>`.
But I expected the router would have a type `Router<{root:{}, blog:{id:string}}>`.

I tried to add type parameter (see `router2`) and it works as expected.

Also I assumed that tsc@2.7.2 cannot infer type of `routes` object and I added type explicitly (the `router3`). It also works right.

Are there any ways to solve this issue without adding types explicitly?
At least I would like to get reasonable explanation why TS treat value types as any in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in Typescript 2.8. It might be related to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22169) issue

[image: Proof]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I downgraded to 2.6.x and it works as expected.

Comment: @Kayo hope it helps. it looks like a bug that got fixed